# Notepad++ Remove Decimal Places

Tags: regex, notepad++

I currently have a long list of code as follows:

```
<line fill="none" x1="555" y1="562.8181152" x2="542.1015625" y2="579.6394043"/>
<line fill="none" x1="542" y1="579.6394043" x2="527.46875" y2="594.4655762"/>
<line fill="none" x1="527.46875" y1="594.4655762" x2="504" y2="613.9626465"/>
<line fill="none" x1="504" y1="613.9626465" x2="481.9648438" y2="629.4460449"/>
<line fill="none" x1="481" y1="629.4460449" x2="461.6015625" y2="641.6647949"/>
<line fill="none" x1="461" y1="641.6647949" x2="441.1074219" y2="650.2966309"/>
<line fill="none" x1="441" y1="650.2966309" x2="424.0859375" y2="655.7995605"/>
<line fill="none" x1="424" y1="655.7995605" x2="394.5" y2="662.2321777"/>
<line fill="none" x1="394.5" y1="662.2321777" x2="368.8945313" y2="665.0407715"/>
<line fill="none" x1="368" y1="665.0407715" x2="351.0014648" y2="665.6970215"/>
<line fill="none" x1="351" y1="665.6970215" x2="332.1748047" y2="665.3688965"/>
<line fill="none" x1="332" y1="665.3688965" x2="311.1508789" y2="662.2321777"/>
<line fill="none" x1="311" y1="662.2321777" x2="287.7905273" y2="655.7995605"/>
<line fill="none" x1="287" y1="655.7995605" x2="267.5742188" y2="648.2351074"/>
<line fill="none" x1="267" y1="648.2351074" x2="243.965332" y2="636.6647949"/>
<line fill="none" x1="243.965332" y1="636.6647949" x2="216.9702148" y2="619.0388184"/>
<line fill="none" x1="216" y1="619.0388184" x2="194.0844727" y2="599.3747559"/>
<line fill="none" x1="194" y1="599.3747559" x2="171.9951172" y2="574.7194824"/>
<line fill="none" x1="171" y1="574.7194824" x2="153.3139648" y2="547.5153809"/>
<line fill="none" x1="153" y1="547.5153809" x2="137.4921875" y2="517.0036621"/>
```

Due to this being rendered on mobile devices as a svg this needs to remove the decimal places leaving it with for example

```
<line fill="none" x1="153" y1="547" x2="137" y2="517"/>
```

instead of

```
<line fill="none" x1="153" y1="547.5153809" x2="137.4921875" y2="517.0036621"/>
```

I know this is possible via regular expression however I've looked around stackoverflow at different examples but could never get my head around regular expression. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex patterns to obtain the desired result:

Replace: `\.(\d)*` with `EMPTY STRING`

To do that, go to "Replace" tab and fill in the above patterns into "Find what:" and "Replace with" fields accordingly.
Don't forget to click on "Regular expression" radio button.

Answer (score 2):

To do this, goto `Search` -> `Replace`.

```
Find: \.\d+
Replace:
```

Output

```
<line fill="none" x1="555" y1="562" x2="542" y2="579"/>
<line fill="none" x1="542" y1="579" x2="527" y2="594"/>
<line fill="none" x1="527" y1="594" x2="504" y2="613"/>
<line fill="none" x1="504" y1="613" x2="481" y2="629"/>
<line fill="none" x1="481" y1="629" x2="461" y2="641"/>
<line fill="none" x1="461" y1="641" x2="441" y2="650"/>
<line fill="none" x1="441" y1="650" x2="424" y2="655"/>
<line fill="none" x1="424" y1="655" x2="394" y2="662"/>
<line fill="none" x1="394" y1="662" x2="368" y2="665"/>
<line fill="none" x1="368" y1="665" x2="351" y2="665"/>
<line fill="none" x1="351" y1="665" x2="332" y2="665"/>
<line fill="none" x1="332" y1="665" x2="311" y2="662"/>
<line fill="none" x1="311" y1="662" x2="287" y2="655"/>
<line fill="none" x1="287" y1="655" x2="267" y2="648"/>
<line fill="none" x1="267" y1="648" x2="243" y2="636"/>
<line fill="none" x1="243" y1="636" x2="216" y2="619"/>
<line fill="none" x1="216" y1="619" x2="194" y2="599"/>
<line fill="none" x1="194" y1="599" x2="171" y2="574"/>
<line fill="none" x1="171" y1="574" x2="153" y2="547"/>
<line fill="none" x1="153" y1="547" x2="137" y2="517"/>
```